# calling JSON from modal popup inside a user control in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, textbox

I have a user control which opens as a modal popup on a child page.
There is a text box in the popup which I am validating for duplicate values for that I have written the following server- and client-side functions.

```
function Check_DuplicateMachineType() {
    var hndDuplicateMachineType = document.getElementById('<%= hndDuplicateMachineType.ClientID %>');
    var txtmachineType = document.getElementById('<%= txtmachineType.ClientID %>');
    if (txtmachineType.value.trim() != '' && txtmachineType.value.trim().toLowerCase() != hndDuplicateMachineType.value) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wucMachineType.ascx/CheckDuplicateMachineType",
            data: '{Item: "' + $("#<%=txtmachineType.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessForMachineType,
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
function OnSuccessForMachineType(response) {        
    var txtmachineType = document.getElementById('<%= txtmachineType.ClientID %>');
    var divMachineTypes = document.getElementById('<%= divMachineTypes.ClientID %>');
    divMachineTypes.innerHTML = '';
    switch (response.d) {
        case "true":
            divMachineTypes.style.display = "inline";
            divMachineTypes.innerHTML = "Machine Type already exist";
            $("#<%=divMachineTypes.ClientID%>")[0].focus();
            $("#<%=hndIsDuplicate.ClientID%>")[0].value = '1';
            break;
        case "false":
            $("#<%=hndIsDuplicate.ClientID%>")[0].value = '0';
            break;
        case "error":
            divMachineTypes.style.display = "inline";
            divMachineTypes.innerHTML = "Error occured";
            break;
    }
}
```

```cs
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CheckDuplicateMachineType(string Item)
{
    CommonClass objCLSCommon = new CommonClass();
    DataLayer dtLayer = new DataLayer();
    try
    {
        string strQuery = "SELECT machineType from MachineType Where machineType ='" + Item + "'";
        DataTable dtCheckDuplicacy = dtLayer.Get_GeneralData(strQuery);
        if (dtCheckDuplicacy.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            return "true";
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        objCLSCommon.LogErrorToFile(objCLSCommon.GetCurrentPageName(), ex.Message.Trim() + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace.Trim());
        return "";
    }
}
```

I don't know why my `wucMachineType.ascx/CheckDuplicateMachineType` function is not being called.
Also there is no error in the error console.

Comment: is `function Check_DuplicateMachineType` being called?  is the `$.ajax` being called?  use Firebug in Firefox or similar HTTP tool to look at any AJAX requests being called.

Comment: yes @dave i am usig ajax modal poup inside usercontrol.now when i pass "MachineType.aspx/CheckDuplicateMachineType" ,then the function is calling perfectly. is their any issue of ".ascx" or ".aspx"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Web Methods] dose not call which is written on user control(.ascx file) .That's the mistake i am doing.

[Web Methods] must  be written on aspx page. (.aspx file).